# Queueing in Delayed_Job with ActiveJobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, rails-activejob

In a controller, I have a post request by an authenticated user firing an ActiveJob.

```
RunReportsJob.perform_later(param1, param2, param3)
```

It works without errors. But if the user presses the button (firing post request) again to trigger RunReportsJob while it was already running, 2 jobs happen at the same time. I setup delayed_job because I thought it was a queueing service, and would keep everything at one job at a time. But this isn't happening. Below is my configuration:

`# app/jobs/run_reports_job.rb:`

```
class RunReportsJob < ActiveJob::Base
      queue_as :RunReports
      include ShopifyApp::Controller
      # --------------------------------------------------------------
      # JOB ERROR MANAGEMENT
      # --------------------------------------------------------------
      rescue_from(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound) do |exception|
           # Do something with the exception
           logger.debug "Hit rescue_from"
      end
      # --------------------------------------------------------------
      # JOB FUNCTION
      # --------------------------------------------------------------
      def perform(param1, param2, param3)
        # some code is performed here
      end
 end
```

`# config/application.rb`:

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job
```

`# config/initializers/delayed_job_config.rb`:

```
Delayed::Worker.max_attempts = 1
Delayed::Worker.max_run_time = 12.hours
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to add some logic before `RunReportsJob.perform_later(param1, param2, param3)` to check for an already queued job priority and increase the priority number (lower number is higher priority according to documentation) in this example the queue:

```
highest_priority = Delayed::Job.where(queue: :RunReports).maximum(:priority)
Delayed::Worker.default_priority = highest_priority + 1 if highest_priority

RunReportsJob.perform_later(param1, param2, param3)
```

`DelayedJob` uses a table to save all the jobs info check the documentation at https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#gory-details

Comment: I need the second Job call to queue after the 1st, not shoot a blank. It appears to me that the code you've presented here does nothing if there is something already in the queue

Comment: Maybe this is what I am looking for?: `Delayed::Worker.read_ahead = 1`. If the default is 5, does that mean the delayed_job tries to run the last 5 available in it's database at the same time?

Comment: oh, I get it now, this could be accomplished using priority, I'm going to modify the answer code

Comment: Neydroid, your code worked by changing the following line: `Delayed::Worker.default_priority(highest_priority + 1) if highest_priority` to `Delayed::Worker.default_priority = highest_priority + 1 if highest_priority`. Yea, the documentation isn't clear. default_priority is a property, not a setter method. If you edit your answer one more time with this change, I will accept your answer and upvote it.

Comment: great that it worked with the change! thanks for the feedback, already updated the answer 